Assistance Needed: Ethereum and Other Coins Stolen from Trust Wallet
I recently set up a Trust Wallet, but unfortunately, a significant amount of my Ethereum, along with a few other cryptocurrencies, has been stolen. I can see the full transaction details, including the recipient's address.
I've already reached out to Trust Wallet support, but after doing some research, I'm concerned that they may not be able to assist further. I'm hoping to get some advice or insights from this forum on potential steps I can take.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Best regards,
Alev

You can use https://metasleuth.io/ for tracking the funds. Once they reach some CEX you could try your best reaching out to them. Unfortunately in most cases there is not much to be done...
There are companies like https://tokenrecovery.com/ which specialize in such matters, but if it's not significant amount like 50k$+ that very unlikely they would consider your case.
I am sorry for your loss - feel you. I would advise to take it as a lesson. Also I can suggest exploring safeWallet as your main wallet, and setting up 2/2 signers - on mobile and desktop achieving 2FA like system. This would effectivly secure your crypto, and even if one of your wallet get compromised scammers cannot do much.
